# How do I keep the MVVM pattern while implementing lookup dialogs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am in the process of recreating a Win32 (Delphi 5) screen using WPF in C# with the MVVM pattern.  The purpose is to create a demo that I can use to push my company to make the move from Delphi 5 to C#.  In this demo I want to do things the "right" way so we have a good example to start with.  With that in mind, I am trying to adhere to MVVM as strictly as possible which is where I am currently running in to a problem.

In the original program/screen we have lookup dialogs that we can attach to edit boxes and grid cells.  The way it works is that the lookup dialog is an implementation of a specific search (i.e. Customer lookup).  When you attach the lookup dialog to a control, it listens to the key press events for the control.  It has a progressive search feature so that when you start typing, if it can find results that start with what you are typing it will insert the first result in control you attached it to.  While doing this it keeps the cursor where you were typing and highlights the part of the data that you typed in so that if you keep typing it can narrow down the results to find the more specific answer you were looking for.  Where the dialog part comes in to play is when you hit the ellipse button next to the control or if you type in something that it couldn't find while doing the progressive search.  In either of those cases it will bring up the lookup gui which will show you all the possible results, provide filters to help you narrow your search down etc.  This gui is visually attached to the control you assigned it to.  It always pops up right under the cell or edit box etc that you assigned it to.

So this lookup dialog is throwing me off when it comes to trying to figure out how to implement it using MVVM.  So far my code mostly pure as far as MVVM goes.  The only code in the Views code behind is the one line creating the ViewModel and assigning it to its DataContext.  The ViewModel makes no references to the view.  But with this lookup dialog the lines seem a little blurred to me.  I envision the lookup having it's own ViewModel.  When you lookup something, say an Item to be put in a Sales Order, we may want to get information like the Item's price from the lookup so that it can be copied in to the Sales Order record.  So to do that the main ViewModel for the screen needs to know about the lookup's ViewModel.  The View for the main screen needs to know about the View for the lookup too though because it has to be able to "attach" the lookup to a gui control so it can listen to key press events and know where to visually popup when it needs to be shown.  I'm not sure if the code determining the visual position of the lookup should reside in the lookups ViewModel which would break the MVVM concept totally or maybe in the lookup's view's code behind which would muddy the purity of the view a bit since now the View isn't just the  XAML.

The original lookup, after being created, would be given a reference to the control that it should attach to.  It would then attach functions within its object to the key press and button click events (our edit boxes can have buttons built-in).  When it was told to popup, it would figure out the current position of the control it is attached to so that it could figure out where to put itself.  In the case of attaching it to a grid, it was actually attached to the column of the grid because there is only one instance of the lookup, and it would figure out the current position of the cell in the grid it is supposed to be popping up under.

What is the best way to do this while still staying in the realm of MVVM.  I really would like to stay as "pure" as possible so I can come back later and add integration and possibly unit tests for the ViewModels in the program and these should be ViewModels that are "headless" (no View).

To make it easier to understand what I am trying to achieve I have included a picture of the screen I am recreating for my demo with the lookup shown.

[image: Demo Window]

Comment: I implemented something like that by creating a Custom Control derived from `Selector` and having a generic `SearchViewModel<T>` with a bunch of delegates such as `Func<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems` and the like.

Comment: BTW, don't `figure out the current position of the cell in the grid`. There's no such thing in WPF. Create a custom control and put that in the Cell instead.

Comment: As an aside, there's no reason that the "View must be only XAML". It's perfectly fine to put `View-Specific` code behind.

Comment: Woah, text.  A lookup dialog can be a custom UI component that takes an instance of a type or interface that defines methods for performing the lookup.  The implementing type would not have anything to do with the UI, and the UI wouldn't have any application logic.  The Aristocrats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  HighCore, would I be able to achieve the same visual as shown in the provided image if I put it in the template for the column?  I don't want the lookup to be confined to the inside of the cell but rather shown right below it.  I am relatively new to WPF so my confusion may just be my lack of knowledge of what is possible in WPF.

Comment: @Fyndor yes, you need a `<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TheTextBox}"/>` or the like. A [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) opens a new HWND and is basically outside of the Visual Tree, therefore it is not constrained to the layout of it's placement target.

Comment: @Fyndor similar to what a `ComboBox` does. You can even base your custom control's Template out of the [Default ComboBox Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx), but I suggest deriving from `Selector` and not `ComboBox` because the latter does a lot of keyboard handling which might not suit your need.

Comment: @HighCore So if I bound the Popup's PlacementTarget to a DataGrid column, it would naturally place on/under/near the cell in that column associated with the current active row?  The cell doesn't exist at design-time because the rows are populated via databinding to a list of objects, so the only thing I have at design time is the column definition.

Comment: @Fyndor the `PlacementTarget` should be the `TextBox` which is inside the `ControlTemplate` for your Custom control. It has nothing to do with any DataGrid column or the like.

Comment: @HighCore Ah.  So really I should probably make 2 Custom Controls.  One that is the lookup itself and one that is made up of a TextBox with a Button next to it along with a popup that targets the TextBox and the Popup will contain the lookup Custom Control.  I guess it really needed 2 anyway since WPF doesn't come out of the box with a TextBox that has a built in button.

Comment: @Fyndor the way I did was to define a `PopupContentTemplate` property in my `SearchBox` control, which then would be used as the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentPresenter` inside the `Popup`.

Comment: @Fyndor Then, it's just a matter of `<SearchBox PopupContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeDataTemplate}"/>` or the like.

Comment: @HighCore Now I need to figure out how to use a generic TextBox custom control with different versions of the popup.  I think I want a lookup base class and I will create custom controls that inherit from that base class that implement the specific lookup needed (Customer, Item, Supplier, etc).  I think you have given me enough info to get started and hopefully Google can help me get the rest of the way.  Maybe a better approach would be to just implement it and then figure out ways to MVVMify it where I have broken the separation between the View and the ViewModel.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HighCore Hehe you basically answered my next comment before I finished writing it :D

Comment: I have a [custom PopupControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) I typically use for dialogs which you might be interested in checking out. Typically my ViewModel would contain properties like `IsPopupVisible` and `PopupDataContext` which determine the Popup visibility and content. It could also be easily modified to determine PopupPosition if needed too.